# How to bake a texure to a single channel (as a mask) using emission node?

Tags: materials, texture-baking

I found some info about baking a mask to a single channel texture with an `Emission Node`. It is an interesting method to use RGB channels (grey picture) to control effects. The baking with light (emission) method is also something that interests me.

Is there any other way to setup such a Shader System?

Comment: This question needs to be reworded/clarified. Right now you are asking something completely different in the question body than in the header (or you are asking two questions). Of course you can use RGB and Alpha channels in a glsl shader/material node.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! We're glad to have you! Keep in mind, this is NOT a forum, and the site expects questions and answers to be of a high quality. That means well-asked, well-researched, and involve some level of effort. Taking the tour will help you understand what we're all about: http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour